# Keras module not found

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I had installed TensorFlow using `pip install --upgrade tensorflow`.
but when I tried importing `tensorflow.keras`, it throws the following error. can anyone help me with this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwFlg.png)

Comment: Do `import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)` What do you get?

Comment: ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3267, in run_code
   exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
 File "<ipython-input-4-ed7bb9a7155c>", line 1, in <module>
  import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)
AttributeError:module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '__version__'
ImportError: DLL load failed:The specified module could not be found.
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `from tensorflow import keras`

or for your case, you will have to do `from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential` to import Sequential model.

Comment: What is the error? when you do `from tensorflow import keras`?